# API Gateway + Fetch API w/ CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, aws-api-gateway

I made an API Gateway and it passes tests on platform. However, when trying to fetch from a React app, I'm running into CORS issues

Here's the fetch call

```
      fetch("my-endpoint", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Amz-Date": "",
          "Authorization":"",
          "X-Api-key": "my-key",
          "X-Amz-Security-Token": ""
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "key": "value" })
      })
```

However, the response that I'm receiving is

```
Acess to fetch at 'my-endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response 
serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Here are the CORS settings that I have:

[image]

Where Access-Control-Allow-Headers includes 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'
My questions are:

1. What needs to change, API or Fetch call?
2. If API Gateway, what settings need to be updated?
3. If Fetch how can the query be updated?

Comment: Did you redeploy after enabling CORS? If you have added CROS via AWS Console in API Gateway page, AWS will automatically add the required configurations. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html

Comment: The problem was actually on the React side, needed to add some CORS parameters such that React didn't block the response. Gateway was fine.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 Can you share what have you added on React side? I'm using Vue 3 and having the same issue.